Not able to SSH into the Compute Engine created by using the Packer Template in GCP
Packer Installation on Local machine:
wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install packer
Packer version :
packer --version
Packer v1.11.0
Packer Template:
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "googlecompute",
      "project_id": "project_Id",
      "source_image_project_id":"project_id",
      "source_image": "image_name",
      "disk_size": "200",
      "communicator": "ssh",
      "use_os_login": false,
      "tags":"ssh",
      "use_iap": true,
      "ssh_timeout":"10m",
      "iap_tunnel_launch_wait":"90",
      "ssh_username": "packer",
      "zone": "asia-south1-a",
      "subnetwork": "subnet_selflink",
      "omit_external_ip": true,
      "use_internal_ip": true
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "local_file_namet",
      "destination": "destination_path"
    }
  ]
}

The above packer template, is able to create a vm using the specified image, in the specified project, But it is failing to ssh into the created vm. It is showing connection timeout error.
Things tried:

Increased the SSH timeout to 10 minutes.
Added the network tag in the Packer template to enable SSH, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Tried to SSH using the IAP tunnel
Executed the same Packer template by creating a VM and modified the template to create a
VM in the same subnet as the  VM, but still encountering a timeout error.
Have added the iap_tunnel_launch_wait to 90 but its not helping, referred the below article for the troubleshooting

https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/googlecompute/latest/components/builder/googlecompute#iap_tunnel_launch_wait
https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/12169
